# Not allowing more than one login in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session, datetime

I have a system which users login to it. Every time a specific user logs in, I store the login datetime in a MySQL database using TIMESTAMP:

Each record in the db has a user_id and login_date and it stored in my att_log table.
However, I want to make sure that users can only login once a day, based on the date . Here my code so far

```
        <?php
        include('conn.php');
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $UserName=$_POST['id_emp']; 
        $Password=$_POST['password'];
        $result=mysql_query("select * from employee where id_emp='$UserName' and password='$Password'" )or die (mysql_error()); 

        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

        if ($count > 0){
        $_SESSION['emp_id']=$row['emp_id'];
        mysql_query("insert into att_log (username,login_date,id)values('$UserName',NOW(),".$row['emp_id'].")")or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

How do I write a right statement to check case if the user_id have login on the same dates, it will reject, before it being insert into att_log table.
With the current code, it will continuously insert the same user again and again at the same date, just different in time.

i want to filter out the specific user on the specific day, since i do count their frequency at end of month, like

```
id_attlog  username   logindate           id   
1           2010    2015-06-20 19:08:19   33
2           2011    2015-06-20 19:08:19   34
3           2011    2015-06-21 19:08:19   34
4           2011    2015-06-22 19:08:19   34


User ID   Day of Attendance
33          3
34          1
```

which user id 34 has log in for 3 days, and user 33 has log in for 1 day only. Thus that why i want the user only able to login once a day. And i still looking for correct way to implement the limitation to the user for them to log in once a day.

Thanks!

Comment: looking at your code, tells me you've syntax errors. Edit: missing a quote `"`. If that is what you're using, then add it. If not, edit your question. Plus make sure you started the session.

Comment: curently no syntax error, but it keep on insert into att_log, repeatedly with the same id_emp in the same date. I just want to restrict 1 id_emp can log one in 1 day

Comment: `("select * from employee where id_emp='$UserName' and password='$Password' )` - Oh? I doubt that very much.

Comment: There surely is a syntax error in your code.

Comment: oh forgot the " there, but still the same id_emp can be stored in the att_log at the same date.

Comment: You need to add a clause in your select to check for a date

Comment: in this case, i just wanted for the user, they can just login once, as proof that they enter the system, part of their attendance as it was what my system are for. For this to happen, i wanted for the user only able to login once a day, 
Thanks for advice, will moved from mysql_

Answer (score 0):

```
// Compare username/password and check last login date is less than today
$result = mysql_query('select a.*, max(b.login_date) as login_date from employee AS a LEFT JOIN att_log AS b ON a.emp_id = b.id where a.emp_id = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($UserName) . '" and a.password = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($Password) . '" and login_date < DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY a.emp_id' ) or die (mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    mysql_query('insert into att_log (username, login_date, id) values("' . mysql_real_escape_string($UserName) . '", NOW(), "' . mysql_real_escape_string($row['emp_id']) . '"') or die(mysql_error());
} else {
    echo 'Access denied';
}
```

or:

```
// Compare username/password
$result = mysql_query('select a.*, max(b.login_date) as login_date from employee AS a INNER JOIN att_log AS b ON a.emp_id = b.id where a.emp_id = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($UserName) . '" and a.password = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($Password) . '" GROUP BY a.emp_id' ) or die (mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// If last login date is greater or equal than the start of today, show access denied message
if (strtotime($row['login_date']) >= strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00')) {
    echo 'Sorry you have already logged in today';
} else {
    mysql_query('insert into att_log (username, login_date, id) values("' . mysql_real_escape_string($UserName) . '", NOW(), "' . mysql_real_escape_string($row['emp_id']) . '"') or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks to MrCarrot, i tried your code, but then i realize that in if (strtotime($row['login_date']), the login_date is called from table employee isn't? but in table employee there is no such, but login_date is in the att_log table . Now im getting error that login_date is yet undefined index.

Comment: I edited my answer to join the two tables together and get the value of `login_date`.  Sorry, this is untested and I haven't eaten yet today.  Good luck

Comment: thanks for you help :D i try around, now getting "u have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1" syntax